# cancan/devise - redirect to requested path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When a user visits a page that they are not authorized to view they get redirected to the login page.   After they log in they are redirected to the site root.   Is there a quick and easy way to redirect them back to the page they initially asked for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a hidden field `referring_page` to your `sign_in`-form to add the `former` referrer to that field and route back to there if its existing, like this:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  params[:referring_page] || super
end
```

It's a manual solution but i prefer it to using complex logic on controller side.

Answer (score 1):

I dont understand what you exactly want to achieve by saying "if a user visits a page that they are not authorized to view they get redirected to the login page. After they log in they are redirected to the site root"

I assume there will be two sets of users one is admin- user and another is non-admin user the way i handle this will be something like this,

Inside  application controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  check_authorization :unless => :devise_controller?
  before_filter :authenticate_user! 

  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    redirect_to root_url, :alert => exception.message
  end

  protected

  def stored_location_for(resource_or_scope)
    nil
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    if current_user.admin?
      #add your desired path
    else
      #redirect to your desired path
    end
  end
end
```